# Add beamer frame options in knitr/rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

I'm trying to add frame numbers to my Beamer presentation written in rmarkdown. However, I would like to suppress the numbers on the title page using the \begin{frame}[plain] option (from the second answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82794/removing-page-number-from-title-frame-without-changing-the-theme). However, when compiling from rmarkdown to tex, the \titlepage already creates a frame environment, so in effect I get a double frame and thus an error.

So when compiling this:

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

I get this in latex:

```
\begin{frame{

  \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
  \end{frame}

\end{frame}
```

In the header.tex I have this:

```
\let\otp\titlepage
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{\otp\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
```

So my workaround now is to just use a plain \maketitle in rmarkdown, then compile to .tex, add the [plain] option, then compile to pdf. However, I would like to avoid that intermediate step. Is this possible in rmarkdown?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rmarkdown` uses `pandoc` to convert a Rmd file to a pdf via beamer/latex. `pandoc` uses [templates](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates) to control how the conversion goes.

One way to deal with your problem is to :

1. [Download the default beamer template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/de574c69686f9eabd50083db1e21b0cc00947cbc/inst/rmd/beamer/default.tex) `rmarkdown` uses and open it.
2. Change line 137 from this :

   ```
   \frame{\titlepage}
   ```

   To this :

   ```
   \frame[plain]{\titlepage}
   ```
3. Add the path to your modified template in your `Rmd` file :

   ```
   ---
   output:
     beamer_presentation:
       includes:
         in_header: header.tex
       template:/path/to/new/template.tex
   ---
   ```

Note that you need to specify the whole path, or store the template where `pandoc` can find it (`~/.pandoc/templates` on a linux machine)

Answer (score 9):

Add `{.plain}` after the title as in:

```
----

# I'm the title {.plain}
```

Source: [Pandoc User’s Guide](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#frame-attributes-in-beamer)